# SSAS: Process cube failed at the end

Tags: ssas

Good morning,

Here, I am faced with a problem when processing a cube on a new server.

When I am connected with the domain administrator or the local administrator of the server and I start the process of the cube, the process works.
Now, when I connect with my user (which is defined in the administrator group), I can deploy the cube but towards the end of the process (at the end of the creation of partitions), I have a failed message with the following message: "The following system error occurred: The request is not supported".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sgj6.png)

The request of the partition is quite standard and the number of rows returned by the partition processing corresponds to the total number of rows of the partition. The problem therefore does not seem to be related to the request, but rather a problem of rights on the user.

User is declared in "Server administrators" in SSAS (SSMS -> Properties -> Security).
User is declared in sysadmin on the database instance.

I use the service account in Impersonation Information from the data source. This service user is declared in Server administrators and as sysadmin.

Where did I miss something?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What’s the command being run in the DDL task? Can you paste it into the question?

Comment: Hi, We’re migrating our BI server. For now, I execute the cube process task manually from SSMS or from an SSIS task.

Comment: Hi, I am encountering the same issue! Have you managed to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I still have not found the solution to the problem, but I have made some progress.

I manage to process a script launched by SQL Job agent type SSAS and executed by the SVC_SQL user.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGgXx.png)

Now, if I connect with SVC_SQL on SSMS and try to browse the cube I still have the error Request is not supported.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXj9c.png)

I don’t understand what the problem is.

If I connect to the cube with an Excel file, I can easily read it.

So if I summarize:

- I cannot process the cube live with SSMS or visual studio otherwise "Request is not supported".
- I cannot navigate the live cube with SSMS otherwise "Request is not supported".
- I can process the cube with a script on SQL Agent with the same user who cannot process under SSMS or VS.
- I can read the cube with Excel in remote access with this same user.